# How can I open an image saved within the app with the android gallery?

Tags: java, android, image, gallery, resolution

I have a little problem with an app I'm designing. I need to be able to open a high-res image (stored in the assets folder of the project), with the android gallery. I have tried many things, like put it in the drawables folder and retrieving the Uri (which gives Out of Memory error). I need to be able to have that high-res image without any type of compression because the user will need to zoom in a lot.

Any idea is welcome, thank you everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to copy your image from assets folder to external memory for the Gallery app being able to display it.

Answer (score 0):

The android application is have a strict restriction of using dynamic memory, it is 16 mb. So if image is larger then at least 15mb trying to load it into memory will undoubtedly encouner with OutOfMemory error. 
Use this library https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view , which is designed, as it seems, exactely for your needs. As follows from description, the main concept is to load large images partially, just a part for current displaing.